# Div wont float over Jquery EasySlider

Tags: jquery, css

Got an issue with a layer not toggling over other content well.

Website http://bit.ly/euXvuJ

On the top right, if you mouse over the "shopping cart" link, a div gets toggled. Well, it's Z-index was set to 5202... the highest on the page. But it still wont float over the jQuery EasySlider that displays products.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the CSS overflow property

http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you remove position relative for #product_showcase_container, it'll resolve the issue with Firefox (at least)